# how to construct formula for lmer dynamically?

Tags: r, lme4

I'm doing mixed model and have 4 variables, x1-x4 alongwith dependent variable y. The class variable is called cla. The present modeling structure is

```
md<-lmer(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+(1+x2|cla)+(1+x4|cla),data=mydata)
```

But, suppose I want to change the model to the following format

```
md<-lmer(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+(1+x2|cla)+(1+x3|cla)+(1+x4|cla),data=mydata)
```

My question is, how could I make this code dynamic, so that I can just choose variable, and it get's incorporated in the model. For just 4 variables, it's not very difficult. But for larger number of variables manually adding variables is quite taxing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepare parts of the formula in advance, glue them together and coerce it to a `formula` object. You can prepare individual parts into its own variable, name them something predictable (`x2`, `x37,`x4`) so that you can automatically find them using`ls(pattern = "")`. You fetch each object using`get`, pass that to`paste`, use a`collapse` argument to glue them together *et voila*.

```
fixed.part <- "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3"

x2 <-"(1+x2|cla)"
x3 <- "(1+x3|cla)"
x4 <- "(1+x4|cla)"

random.part <- paste(sapply(ls(pattern = "^x"), get), collapse = " + ")
formula(paste(fixed.part, random.part, sep = " + "))

y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 + x2 | cla) + (1 + x3 | cla) + (1 + x4 | cla)
```

If you want less manual control, you can construct a "blank" random part, add an appropriate number and the rest is the same as above.

```
x <- "(1+x%s|cla)"
random.part <- paste(sprintf(x, 1:10), collapse = " + ")
formula(paste(fixed.part, random.part, sep = " + "))

y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 + x1 | cla) + (1 + x2 | cla) + (1 + x3 | 
    cla) + (1 + x4 | cla) + (1 + x5 | cla) + (1 + x6 | cla) + 
    (1 + x7 | cla) + (1 + x8 | cla) + (1 + x9 | cla) + (1 + x10 | 
    cla)
```

Comment: @Beta I'v edited the question to show a method for a bit larger scale.